# create CMS for wordpress theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

I have converted HTML site to WordPress theme and uploaded it to the server, now i want to create CMS for this theme , but there are another active theme now and those are the [the current pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oy5rO.png).

how can I create a new page for my new converted theme without losing or effecting the current themes and the contents?

this the themes [the active theme and my new covered theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZukD.png)

Comment: You cant have both themes. modify current theme and add custom page template with new pages and add to current theme

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe I would advise you to create a Child Theme: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Then you will be able to overrides only the templates you want if you conform to WordPress' Template Hierarchy: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/